How to re-render dropdown with search text data filtered
I am using a bootstrap selectpicker with knockout.js binding which has multiselect as well as data-live-search properties on.
Here is a scenario
Steps:

Open dropdown, type ‘cat’ in dropdown
Due to live data search, while typing every letter, list gets filtered and at the end, I will get only those list items who includes ‘cat’
I select a option from filtered list, and the list gets refreshed as i am assigning selectedData observable a new set of values.

Now, the issue is, list gets refreshed but it doesn’t consider search text value while rendering
What I need is to re-render with search text value taken into consideration so that after refreshing it should show items related to search text.
Is there a way I can do it with either knockout code or jQuery

Kindly create a minimal reproducible example
